# PHP class not loading when class file is included

Tags: php

I'm trying to load a class file that has some blogging tools in it that work with my CMS. When the file is loaded at the top it says `$blog = new blog;` and then goes on to call a function to display posts. It's not displaying anything though. This is the top of the file where everything is started:

```
$blog = new blog;
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {

  if ($_GET['action'] === "Blog") {

    if (!isset($_GET['mode'])) {

     $blog->viewBlog();
     var_dump($parser);
    }
  }
}

class blog {
//Class stuff
}
```

When the `$_GET['action']` variable equals to `blog`. it should render the blog, but it doesn't.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the action has to equal Blog not blog.

Comment: @Wizzard Either way it's still not working

Comment: Try defining it before using it?

Comment: @DissidentRage What do you mean

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's look at your logic

```
1. if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
  2. if ($_GET['action'] === "Blog") {
    3. if (!isset($_GET['mode'])) {
```

You say - if there's a variable called `action` and it equals to **Blog** and **if at the same time** there's no variable called `mode` - render a blog.

In your case, there could be two issues

First one - `blog` is not `Blog`. Because of this, `if ($_GET['action'] === "Blog")` is never true and therefore no render.

Second one - Are you totally sure there's no `mode` in query string? That could be an issue too.

Comment: Okay, I removed anything that has to do with mode for the moment. Now what happens is when I go to the page (with the correct url ("Blog")) The page slightly extends, as if something should be there, but it is not. There aren't any errors, but I will try calling it directly from the file instead of including it.

Answer (score 0):

`$blog->viewBlog();` should actually be `$blog = $this -> viewBlog();`

Comment: No actually it should not be `$blog = $this -> viewBlog();` (if you look at the code once again)